# Problemas con imágenes en dominio

Tags: dominio

tengo problemas para visualizar cualquier formato de imágenes en mi dominio
ni GIF, JPG, PNG, las únicas extensiones que puedo visualizar es JFIF.

Tengo un multiservidor con varios dominios
cuando acceso desde el dominio de mi servidor (mxnpi.space/pi.com.mx)
http://mxnpi.space/pi.com.mx/becarios.php
puedo observar dichas imagenes con extensiones antes mencionadas.

Pero al momento de acceder desde mi dominio (www.pi.com.mx)
http://www.pi.com.mx/becarios.php
ya no observo las imágenes.

Alguien tiene idea de como puedo solucionar esto?

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Codigo? Imagen muestra? Tipo de dominio? Codigo de ejecucion en el navegador? Adivinamos?

Comment: Ya he modificado la pregunta, gracias.

Comment: La pregunta no va a servir en el momento del futuro en el que tus sitios ya no existan. Por favor, trata de incluir la información de forma que le sirva a cualquiera que lea tu pregunta y las respuestas en el futuro.

Comment: Según [esta captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4eeC.png), el problema es que el servidor responde HTTP 403 a las peticiones de imágenes. Revisa la configuración de seguridad, los filtros, desde dónde se permiten ciertas peticiones, etc. Sin más información, no hay cómo más ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN**

Resulta que en mi Cpanel tenía activado la protección de enlaces, por lo cuál únicamente tuve que agregar el dominio a la que le otorgo permisos para acceder a las imágenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

estas poniendo la ruta mal:
http://www.pi.com.mx/img/becas.jpg
no existe dicha ruta debes colocar bien la ruta de preferencia ruta absoluta no relativa!
mientras que
http://mxnpi.space/pi.com.mx/img/becas.jpg
si existe!
eso es todo tu problema!